# Blank window after MsgBox in HTA

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am creating an application in HTA using VBScript, which will let you select your a file directory for a video game, and will save it to a file. Then you can press the buttons "French" or "German", which will run batch files that will change the game language to either French or German, which is why the game directory is saved so it can be read by the batch file.

When one of the MsgBox's appears and is closed, the window of the application bugs out and the background turns blank and just shows "1". I've tried searching around but I can't find any issue like this. I'm guessing its trying to show an error or something, though I don't really know what it means.

A lot of this is copied from the internet and modified slightly.[This is how the application looks like when you first start it, after you press French or German, and after you press OK or X on the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqyRK.png)

```html
<html>   
<head>   
<title>SelectInput</title>   
<hta:application id  = "objHTA"    
     applicationName = "SelectInput"  
     border          = "thin"  
     borderStyle     = "normal"  
     caption         = "yes"  
     maximizeButton  = "no"  
     minimizeButton  = "yes"  
     showInTaskbar   = "yes"  
     scroll          = "no"  
     singleInstance  = "yes"  
     sysmenu         = "yes"  
     version         = "1.0"/>   
</head>   
<script language="vbscript">   
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
'Initialization  Section      
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, scriptBaseName
On Error Resume Next
   Set objFSO     = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   scriptBaseName = objFSO.GetBaseName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Wscript.Quit
   End If
On Error Goto 0
CenterWindow   
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
'Functions Processing Section      
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
'Name       : ProcessScript -> Primary Function that controls all other script processing.      
'Parameters : None          ->   
'Return     : None          ->      
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
Function ProcessScript(buttonPressed)
 Dim fileSpec, folderSpec
 Dim objFSO, objFolder, objShell, objTextFile, objFile, Wsc
 Dim strDirectory, strFile, strText
 strDirectory = "C:\test"
 strFile = "\directory.txt"
 strText = folderSpec

   Select Case LCase(buttonPressed)
      Case "folder"
         If Not SelectFolder(folderSpec) Then
            Exit Function
         Else
            MsgBox "You selected " & folderSpec, vbInformation
   
   ' Create the File System Object
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   ' Check that the strDirectory folder exists
   If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
   Else
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
    WScript.Echo "Just created " & strDirectory
   End If

   If objFSO.FileExists(strDirectory & strFile) Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
   Else
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & strFile)
    WScript.Echo "Just created " & strDirectory & strFile
   End If 

   set objFolder = nothing
   set objFile = nothing
   ' OpenTextFile Method needs a Const value
   ' ForAppending = 8 ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
   Const ForWriting = 2

   set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
   (strDirectory & strFile, ForWriting, True)

   ' Writes strText every time you run this VBScript
   objTextFile.WriteLine folderSpec
   objTextFile.Close

   ' Bonus or cosmetic section to launch explorer to check file
   If err.number = vbEmpty then
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.run ("Explorer" &" " & strDirectory & "\" )
   Else WScript.echo "VBScript Error: " & err.number
   End If
         End If
   End Select   
End Function   
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
'Name       : CenterWindow -> Centers the HTA window vertically and horizontally in the middle of the screen.   
'Parameters : None         ->      
'Return     : None         ->      
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
Function CenterWindow   
   Dim wmi, results, result   
   Dim displayWidth, displayHeight, x, y   
   On Error Resume Next  
      Set wmi     = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")   
      Set results = wmi.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_DesktopMonitor")   
      For Each result In results   
         displayWidth  = result.ScreenWidth   
         displayHeight = result.ScreenHeight   
      Next  
      x = (displayWidth  - 250) / 2   
      y = (displayHeight - 120) / 2   
      If x < 0 Or y < 0 Then  
         x = 0   
         y = 0   
      End If  
      window.resizeTo 500,500   
      window.moveTo x, y   
   On Error Goto 0   
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Name       : SelectFolder -> Opens the shell object to allow the user to browse for and select the file on their computer.
'Parameters : folderSpec   -> Output: The UNC folder path.
'Return     : SelectFolder -> Returns an False or True and the UNC path of the file selected.
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function SelectFolder(folderSpec)
   Dim objShell, objFolder
   SelectFolder = False
   On Error Resume Next
      Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         Exit Function
      End If
      Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, scriptBaseName, 0)
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         Exit Function
      Else
         folderSpec = objFolder.Self.Path
         If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Exit Function
         End If
      End If      
   On Error Goto 0
   SelectFolder = True 
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Name       : SelectFile -> Opens a dialog box to allow the user select a file on their computer.
'Parameters : folderSpec -> Output: The UNC folder path.
'           : fileName   -> Output: The full file name including the folder path.
'           : filter     -> A string containing the filter for the UserAccounts.CommonDialog object.
'Return     : SelectFile -> Returns an False or True and the name of the file selected.
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function French
 dim shell, answer
 If objFSO.FileExists("C:\test\directory.txt") Then
  set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
  shell.run "French.bat"
  set shell=nothing
  answer=MsgBox("Language is now French",0,"French")
  document.write(answer)
 Else
  answer=MsgBox("Please select your game directory first",0,"Error")
  document.write(answer)
 End If
End Function

Function German
dim shell, answer
 If objFSO.FileExists("C:\test\directory.txt") Then
  set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
  shell.run "German.bat"
  set shell=nothing
  answer=MsgBox("Language is now French",0,"French")
  document.write(answer)
 Else
  answer=MsgBox("Please select your game directory first",0,"Error")
  document.write(answer)
 End If
End Function
</script>
<body style = "font:8pt tahoma; color:white; background-color:#3A6EA5">   
   <table align = center width = "100%" height = "50" border = "0">   
      <caption>Please select a folder</caption>   
      <tr height = "25">
         <td align = center> <input id = runbutton0 type = "button" name = "folderButton0" value = "Select Folder" onClick = 'ProcessScript("folder")'></td>
   <td align = center> <input id = runbutton1 type = "button" name = "languageButton0" value = "French" onClick = 'French'></td>
   <td align = center> <input id = runbutton1 type = "button" name = "languageButton1" value = "German" onClick = 'German'></td>
      </tr>   
   </table> 
</body>
```

Comment: When I run your HTA, after the msgbox, I get an error `Variable is undefined: WScript`. See the _Why Can’t I Use Wscript.Echo?_ section in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've now read that section, and removed the wscript.echo functions and replaced it with MsgBox's, now they appear like they should. However, my main issue with the blank screen still persists. I have no idea what it can be.

Comment: I fixed the problem, it was the document.write(answer).